# How can I fold an inflated mesh?

Tags: cloth-simulation, unreal-engine, hook-modifier

I'm trying to animate a foldable cloth. First I inflated the mesh with a pin system to get puffy stripes. Now I try to fold it by creating a Hook for each stripe but I'm struggling to get something that looks natural, it gets stretched. The movement is a rotation, the picture shows the mesh at the "unfolded" position. I tried an armature too, but it did not look like it was folding.

The end goal is to export the animated mesh to unreal engine. How could I achieve a folding movement I could export to unreal?

[image: inflated_cloth_to_fold_down]